# Retrieving objects from localStorage works with console log but not on the page

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I just started learning the localStorage API, and I'm trying to store associative arrays (Objects) and retrieve it. I'm using `JSON.stringify` when storing and `JSON.parse` when retrieving. However, when I use the `element.innerHTML` it shows `[object]['object]` although the `console.log` works fine, (shows the object with all the data). I want it to show in this format:

Id: 1

Name: John

Surname: Doe

Position: Lawyer

Id: 2

Name: Sally

Surname: Stevens

Position: CEO

```
    var msg_display = document.getElementById("msg_display");

    var employees = [
                 {
                  'id': 1,
                  'name':'John',
                  'surname':'Doe',
                  'position':'Lawyer'
                 },
                 {
                  'id': 2,
                  'name':'Sally',
                  'surname':'Stevens',
                  'position':'CEO'
                 },
                 {
                  'id': 3,
                  'name':'Martin',
                  'surname':'Gordons',
                  'position':'Accountant'
                 }
                ];



    localStorage.setItem("employees", JSON.stringify(employees));

    var employee_list = localStorage.getItem("employees");
    employee_list = JSON.parse(employee_list);

     for(var i = 0; i < employee_list.length; i++){
        console.log(employee_list[i]);

        msg_display.innerHTML = "id: " + employee_list[i] + "<br>";
        msg_display.innerHTML+= "name: " + employee_list[i] + "<br>";
        msg_display.innerHTML+= "surname: " + employee_list[i] + "<br>";
        msg_display.innerHTML+= "position: " + employee_list[i] + "<br>";

     }
```

I know there are some libraries for working with localStorage, but I don't want to start working with them before I understand the limitations of working without them. Thanks in advance

Comment: What you need to show instead of `[object]['object]` ?

Comment: console.log is capable of displaying objects in a way that makes sense, but when you force them into a string context (as you are doing, when you append it to innerHTML), that is not necessarily the case. If the object does not have its own toString method, then `[object Object]` is what you get in such a case. So you will need to access the individual, scalar object properties you want to show here.

Comment: I just edited the question,

Comment: @CBroe and how would I do that? I can't find the solution  you suggested online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are retrieving the object itself instead of value. change the for loop to below

```
for(var i = 0; i < employee_list.length; i++){
            console.log(employee_list[i]);

            msg_display.innerHTML = "id: " + employee_list[i].id + "<br>";
            msg_display.innerHTML+= "name: " + employee_list[i].name + "<br>";
            msg_display.innerHTML+= "surname: " + employee_list[i].surname + "<br>";
            msg_display.innerHTML+= "position: " + employee_list[i].position + "<br>";

         }
```

Comment: OK. it prints only 1 item, the last. I don't understand why it's not running through all iterations.

Comment: yes because you are keep on changing the same element "msg_display". So at last iteration last value is assigned

Comment: If you want to create multiple elements for all the employees you need to create same number of elements like "msg_display". For dynamically creating an element in js refer this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp

Comment: This is weird, as I always used the += and it appends everything on the same element.